# TSQL Multiple Inserts

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Received a query in this format for a data import...is there any equivelent in TSQL where you would only have to use "insert into blah" once? (so that I can convert this script)

```
insert into marital_status (id,description) 
values
   (1,'Married'),
   (2,'Separated'),
   (3,'Never Married'),
   (4,'Divorced'),
   (5,'Widowed'),
   (6,'Co-Habitation'),
   (7,'No Response')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This **is** a T-SQL script - for Server 2008 - unforutnately, in 2005, you don't have this feature available :-(

You need to write this query like this:

```
insert into marital_status (id,description) 
values(1,'Married')
insert into marital_status (id,description) 
values(2,'Separated')
insert into marital_status (id,description) 
values(3,'Never Married')
insert into marital_status (id,description) 
values(4,'Divorced')
insert into marital_status (id,description) 
values(5,'Widowed')
insert into marital_status (id,description) 
values(6,'Co-Habitation')
insert into marital_status (id,description) 
values(7,'No Response')
```

Comment: ah...Still on 2005 so I'm not as familiar with the latest TSQL as I would like to be. This is the type of answer I thought I would get...thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative would be:

```
insert into marital_status (id,description) 
    SELECT 1,'Married'       UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'Separated'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'Never Married' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'Divorced'      UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,'Widowed'       UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,'Co-Habitation' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,'No Response'
```